# Java EE 7 EJB Authentication using WildFly - security annotations don't work

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly, java-ee-7, wildfly-18

I am trying to establish a security domain using wildfly 18.0.1. These are the settings I use:

standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="my-security-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="users.properties"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I created user with add-user.bat and created files: users.properties and roles.properties filled with created user data.

IntelliJ doesnt's seem to recognize security annotations and I can't import them:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(name = "HelloWorldType", portName = "HelloWorldPort", targetNamespace = "https://soap.soa.pl/lab1/ws")
@SecurityDomain("my-security-domain") // in standalone.xml
@DeclareRoles({"MyRole"}) 
@WebContext(contextRoot="lab1", urlPattern="/HelloWorld", authMethod="BASIC", transportGuarantee="NONE")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)
public class HelloWorld {

    @WebMethod()
    @RolesAllowed("MyRole")
    public String sayHello(@WebParam(name = "message") String message) {
        return "Here is the message: '" + message + "'";
    }
}
```

Also, now I'm not able to start wildfly serwer:

```
18:49:25,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) starting
18:49:26,643 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.10.4.Final
18:49:27,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
18:49:27,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
18:49:27,321 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "lab1-ear.ear")]) - failure description: "WFLYSRV0137: No deployment content with hash 5cddb572897ba715135a11fe8d8c7c56f30099b5 is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'lab1-ear.ear'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart."
18:49:27,326 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
18:49:27,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 10.0.3.Final) stopped in 7ms
```

I have no idea why, especially the annotations, don't work.. please help.

Comment: Did you try the remedy detailed in your log extract at `18:49:27,321`?... `To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart."`

Comment: Also: [1] Replace the screen shot of your code with the actual source code in text form. [2] [Wildfly 19 is now available](https://wildfly.org/news/2020/03/18/WildFly19-Final-Released/) so - if possible - you might consider upgrading (though I don't think that would resolve your issue).

Comment: Indeed, removing deployment from configuration helped, the proper one was added automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to locate the jar file providing these annotation classes and add it to the [Module Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

If your project is Gradle or Maven managed, add the dependency to `build.gradle`/`pom.xml` instead.

Comment: Thank you, the needed arttifactIds are: jbossws-api, jboss-annotations-ejb3, javax.annotation-api